# antd button wrap text

Tags: html, css, antd

Using the [antd](https://ant.design/) package (v3) I would like to have a button with a fixed width that wraps around its text and linebreaks when needed so the text fits inside the button and borders appear around the text correctly.

Here is what I have tried at the moment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/antoine_chopin/pen/YzqwxOq?editable=true&editors=001%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fant.design%2Fcomponents%2Fbutton%2F). I noted that using whitespace: normal works with  but not with antd

```
const {  Button  } = antd;

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
  <div style={{width:"100px"}}>
    <Button block type="primary" ghost style={{whiteSpace: "normal"}}>Wrap around text</Button>
  </div>
  <button style={{width: '100px', whiteSpace: 'normal'}} type='primary'>Wrap around text</button>
  </>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The class **"ant-btn"** has fixed height property, you should need to override it by auto and it works.

```
<Button block type="primary" ghost style={{whiteSpace: "normal",height:'auto',marginBottom:'10px'}}>Wrap around text</Button>
```

Comment: Damn, the solutions are always rather simple, yet I can never figure it out! Thanks shahid